# Is it possible to have lasers that travel slower than light?

Tags: science-fiction, weapons, space, lasers

In science-fiction, what are referred to as "laser guns" are usually just plasma weapons that travel slower than the speed of light. But I want to have *actual* laser - not plasma - weapons in my universe, but I don't want them to travel at the speed of light. Is that possible?

Comment: I think this is pretty far from what you want, but [slow light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_light) is a thing.  We've slowed light down to 17m/s.

Comment: I'm not sure where you get the idea that a [laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser#Solid-state_lasers) is a plasma weapon, or where the idea that plasma can be made to travel at the speed of light. For the sake of clarity, you should do at least a minimum of research so that you can then ask the question that you mean to.

Comment: @RogueAnt I never said that all lasers are plasma or that plasma travels at the speed of light - I just said that in Sci-Fi, when someone says "laser gun", they usually mean plasma weapons that aren't related to lasers and don't travel at the speed of light.

Comment: I'm pretty sure with the [tag:reality-check] tag, you'll be wanting to define your terms. Laser usually means laser after all. You should also be aware that it's usual to wait 24 too 48 hours before awarding the accepted answer tick as it discourages our international audience from contributing other (perhaps better) answers.

Comment: @RogueAnt Oh. Okay then.

Comment: Sorry, but the q looks like - some guys out there are wrong, but they are not wrong enough, I wanna dive even deeper and be more wrong than they are. By definition speed of ligth in a vacuum is The speed of ligth. So you have to have some medium which travels below that speed, hmm maybe some plasma lol, which creates equivalent of or close to a "super conductive optic fiber" which contains your laser energy, lol.

Comment: @MolbOrg Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: Demigan basically did it, his answer is similar to that. I'm strongly in a 'no' camp, and if to suggest I would suggest re-evaluate the weapon you mentiont as plasma one, what it actually is and basically not reinvent things. Willk's answer is actually not bad - as alternative solution, lol. But got an idea ... plasma shot you see isn't an actual shot, but a preparation required to counter reflective coatings and such, once plasma reaches a target actual laser shot is made at wavelength which this plasma can absorb, effectively increasing absorbtion of a shot by a target from 10% to 90%

Comment: @The-Anonymous: Just whose science fiction are you talking about when you say "...when someone says "laser gun", they usually mean plasma weapons...".  You need to substantiate your claim, and possibly upgrade your choice of reading material :-)

Comment: @jamesqf For one, star wars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but not in a way you will like.

A laser is electromagnetic radiation which never has mass and will only travel at lightspeed. While we have slowed down light, it requires a medium or material to do it*. So unless that medium or material is inbetween you and your target all the time you are out of luck.

However, what if you change this around? Rather than fire a beam of light, you fire a carrier that holds the light? Say you use a way to stop the light using a metamaterial, and at impact this light is released? It would have the added benefit of being potentially bullet-shaped and capable, but all the lightbeams and pulsed flashes you expect are gone.

*from @CortAmmon 's comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_light

Comment: Yeah yeah shoot a spool of super "conductive" fibre optics, isn't it denying the laser here as useful energy carrier, eh.

Answer (score 8):

Lasers are not plasma weapons.

Plasma is a "soup" of free electrons and ionized atomic nuclei.
Lasers are coherent beams of photons.

Photons travel always at the velocity of light in the medium they propagate in ($c$ in vacuum, $c/n$ in a medium other than vacuum, with $n$ being its refractive index). End of the story.

**N.B.** Since $n$ is always bigger than 1, in any medium other than vacuum the photons travel slower than *the speed of light in vacuum*.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question...

Comment: @The-Anonymous, it does. A _Laser_ will always travel at the speed of light. If it were to be "slow" it would not be a laser, it would be a laser-adjacent weapon that shoots handwavium beams

Comment: The short answer to the question is "no"

Comment: "n is always bigger than 1" Strictly not true. Phase velocity can exceed c. By definition n = c/v. ...

v > c ⇒ n < 1.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean lasers going slower than $c$, as in the speed of light in a vacuum, then your only choice is shooting them in a medium other than the vacuum of space. Light is slower when travelling through a gas medium such as an atmosphere. However, the difference in speed between a vacuum and an atmosphere such as ours is practically negligible.

You would need a very special medium such as a [Bose-Einstein condensate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate) to really slow down light (its speed falls to 17m/s in such a medium).

Notice that in any case slowing down a laser will not allow you to see it coming.

As an alternative, consider [laser powered rockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_propulsion). Basically you shoot a rocket, but instead of the rocket burning fuel in order to accelerate, you push it with lasers. This allows them to go arbitrarily much further and faster, and depending on the power you spend they might hit the target as a red or white hot stream of molten metal that from a distance might look like a laser beam as seen in some videogames.

Comment: If the speed of a laser is 17m/s, why won't it be visible?

Comment: @The-Anonymous laser not being visible has nothing to do with speed. The things you see are photons bouncing from an object into your eyes. You don't see an apple, you see photons that bounced from an apple. A laser is a beam of photons. It's literally not possible for other photons to bounce of of those and reach your eyes, which would be necessary for you to see the laser.

Comment: Huh... Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: @The-Anonymous to be fair, you can see laser beams in smoke - I don't know if the Bose-Einstein condensate is as see through as regular dry ice, but if it is, you could maybe see the beam if it is not coming towards you (provided you are outside the condensate). That is, you could see it on its way to someone else. However, if it is coming right at you, no matter the medium, you only detect it when it hits you.

Comment: Upvoted even though, technically, even light moving through jello is traveling at "the speed of light" Even if that's slower than the speed of light in a vacuum.

Comment: @The Square-Cube Law: To be accurate, you aren't seeing the laser beam itself in smoke, you are seeing some of the photons that were in it but got scattered out of the beam by the smoke particles.  No different than your car's headlights on a clear night, vs fog or snow.

Answer (score 3):

Not an actual laser, no. Laser is *light*, and by definition, the speed of any light is the speed of light. *In vacuo* that is ~300.000 km/s or so.

But you can *cheat*. Your "laser" might be some mixture of (*waves hands quickly*) light ions in an electromagnetically bound [self-contained matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_matter), sort of a [Kugelblitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_lightning). The energy contents of the "package" is several orders of magnitude beyond that of a simple laser, which explains why it is preferred to the latter, even though its speed is lower and avoiding a hit is possible. You could call this a Kugelblitz device, a Rydberg projector, or a "soliton gun".

Comment: “I always call it a goober.” - Spider-Man

Answer (score 2):

**Don't shoot straight.**

Suppose I want to go get some Jolly Ranchers.  The bodega that has all the flavors is 1 mile away.  My Chevy Nova only goes 100 miles per hour.  But I want it to take all day to get there.

I take a circuitous route.  I set off in the opposite direction and go through town, laying on the horn, taking in the sights.

So too your laser.  You can have it get there slowly even at the speed of light if you send your light somewhere else, reflect it, reflect it, curve it, reflect it etc.

If you are not talking about a banked shot from the Death star but little flying lasers of the "pew pew" variety, you could create extradimensional reflectors.  Extra dimensions do not violate physics.  If your beam is bouncing off reflectors in adjacent third dimensions that could slow it down; from your standpoint it is going in a straight line but it is actually going much, much farther when you count the extradimensional excursions.

Comment: Yeah! That makes sense. But why can't the same thing be done for a death star shot?

Comment: @The-Anonymous  OK you talked me into it.  Death star shot too!

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to be able to watch the beam of light travel like in movies, that's not going to work.

However, one possibility is that pulling the trigger only begins the process of sending the beam - like a camera flash, there's a charge-up followed by a discharge a little bit later. The charge-up can't happen in advance because it leaks away too quickly to be practical, though.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answerers have already pointed out, lasers are by definition light, and light by definition always travels through space at the speed of light in whatever medium it's travelling through. So you have two options: either it must travel through some medium with a lower speed of light, or it must travel through more space than just the Euclidean straight-line distance from the start to the end of its trajectory.

Other answers have already proposed either changing the medium or changing the trajectory to not be a straight line. I think there is only one more possibility: warp space around the laser beam, so that the straight line trajectory covers more spatial distance than it would in a flat spacetime. An [Alcubierre warp drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) is a hypothetical device which warps space in order to achieve "faster-than-light" travel for something which cannot travel *through* space faster than light; imagine something like this in reverse, which warps space to achieve "slower-than-light" travel for something which cannot travel *through* space slower than light.

Now, why anyone would go to all this trouble in order to make their weapons slower is beyond me... but if you can invent a plausible reason for it in your story, go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Realistically no, a electromagnetic wave will only propagate at the speed of light in that material.(air) It can change very slightly with things like [temperature and pressure](http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/1998-02/888690999.Ph.r.html) but not to the extreme levels needed for it to be perceptible to human senses.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included a hard science tag, so, sure! Just have a gun that alters the local speed of light so that lasers go slower than the speed of light. Perhaps they could store up light to make a more powerful laser.

You control the physical laws of your universe, you can them do whatever you want. It may not be physically possible in our universe, but in a sci fi universe it can be.